# NonTransientFlatFileException in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I was trying to read a CSV file having 100 records and processing them in a batch of 10 records in one go. Everything is working fine but after processing all the records, i am getting

> org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException:
>   Unable to read from resource: [class path resource
>   [csv/input/VMwareImport.csv]] and the root cause is
>   org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition
>   handler returned an unsuccessful step.

Below is my job xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<import resource="../config/context.xml" />

<bean id="report" class="com.abc.model.VMware" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.abc.CustomItemProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="threadName" value="#{stepExecutionContext[name]}" />
</bean>

<batch:job id="vmImport">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<batch:step id="slave">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="xmlItemWriter"
            processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" />
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="rangePartitioner" class="com.abc.partition.RangePartitioner" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />



<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

    <property name="resource" value="classpath:csv/input/VMwareImport.csv" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="SubscriptionId,TemplateName,ResourcePool,CpuCount,MemorySize,Network,DiskSize,
                                                    StorageCluster,DHCP,StaticIP,Subnet,Gateway,DNS1,DNS2,
                                                    DtapTag,FinTag,TechTag,TshirtTag,BackupTag " />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.abc.VMwareFieldSetMapper" />

                <!-- if no data type conversion, use BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper to map 
                    by name <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper"> 
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" /> </bean> -->
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean> 

<!-- <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="com.abc.VMwareReaderFromFile" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:csv/input/VMwareImport.csv" />
</bean> -->

<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="com.abc.DummyWriter">
    <!-- <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/report.xml" /> <property 
        name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" /> <property name="rootTagName" 
        value="report" /> -->
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"> 
    <property name="classesToBeBound"> <list> <value>com.abc.model.VMware</value> 
    </list> </property> </bean> -->
```

Complete Exception StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException: Unable to read from resource: [class path resource [csv/input/VMwareImport.csv]]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:220)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:173)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:155)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:115)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:310)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:201)
    ... 23 more

SEVERE: Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:111)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
    at com.fujitsu.App.main(App.java:27)
```

Comment: Provide us the complete stacktrace. This is incomplete information.

Comment: I have made the edits. Please check.

Comment: Somewhere down the line , it looks to be a concurrency issue. What are you partitioning at ? `FlatFileItemReader` is not thread safe and there might be some conflict. More details about your partitioning is needed. Also, just a suggestion, in today's time , don't write XML config but use Java Configurations.

Answer (score 4):

Your cvsFileItemReader needs to be step scoped.  Whichever partition finishes first is closing the stream so the other partitions are unable to continue reading.