# NonTransientFlatFileException in Spring Batch with EnabledBatchProcessing Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to spring Batch.I am trying to run a job again and again with different parameters and I am getting this exception

> org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException:Unable to read from resource: [class path resource[data.txt]]

I understand that the Reader needs to be StepScope and I have used annotation @EnableBatchProcessing.
I am not able to fix this.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.PartitionHandler;
import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner;
import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class jobdesc {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    public Job newJob() throws InterruptedException {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("newJob")
            .start(newStepMaster())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean Step newStepMaster() throws InterruptedException {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("newStepMaster")
            .partitioner("newStep", partitioner())
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
            .step(newStep())
            .gridSize(10)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler partitionHandler() throws InterruptedException {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler retval = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        retval.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        retval.setStep(newStep());
        retval.setGridSize(10);

        return retval;

    }

    @Bean
    public Step newStep() throws InterruptedException {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("newStep")
            . < person, person > chunk(1)
            .reader(reader1())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer1())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Partitioner partitioner() {

        return new Partitioner() {
            public Map < String, ExecutionContext > partition(int gridsize) {
                System.out.println("Partitioner has been started \n");
                System.out.println("value of gridsize is :" + gridsize);
                Map < String, ExecutionContext > partitionMap = new HashMap < String, ExecutionContext > ();
                int startingIndex = 0;
                int endingIndex = 10;
                for (int i = 0; i < gridsize; i++) {
                    ExecutionContext ec = new ExecutionContext();
                    ec.putInt("startingIndex", startingIndex);
                    ec.putInt("endingIndex", endingIndex);
                    startingIndex = endingIndex + 1;
                    endingIndex += 10;

                    partitionMap.put("Thread :-" + i, ec);

                }
                System.out.println("created partition of size" + partitionMap.size());
                return partitionMap;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    ItemReader < person > reader1() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        FlatFileItemReader < person > reader = new FlatFileItemReader < person > ();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data.txt"));
        DefaultLineMapper defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {
            "age",
            "name"
        });
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper < person > beanWrapperFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper < person > ();
        beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setTargetType(person.class);
        defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
        defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(beanWrapperFieldSetMapper);
        reader.setLineMapper(defaultLineMapper);
        //        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //        System.out.println("reader sleeping");
        return reader;

    }

    @Bean
    ItemWriter < person > writer1() {
        return new ItemWriter < person > () {

            public void write(List < ? extends person > list) throws Exception {
                for (person persontemp: list) {
                    System.out.println("writing item" + persontemp.getName() + "   " + persontemp.getAge());
                }
            }
        };

    }


}
```

Comment: similar query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546294/nontransientflatfileexception-in-spring-batch

Comment: Are you sure the file `data.txt` is in the classpath? Have you tried to use `FileSystemResource` with a full path to the file? Other than that, you have a design issue: You are using a partitioned step with a partitioner that creates reading indexes but those indexes are not use anywhere. Each reader is reading the whole file.

Comment: yes I am sure data.txt is in the classpath. Ignore the desing issue.

Comment: If we can ignore the design issue then remove the partitioning setup and try again.

Comment: Is the prior job still running?   Sounds like it does not like multiple steps concurrently touching the same resource, or the reader might be locking the file so other things can not touch it.

Comment: yes that the problem reader was locking the file.